# Exclude directory from webpack watch

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to exclude a symlinked module in node_modules from webpack watch so that webpack does not automatically rebuild when contents inside of the module change

I tried adding the following plugin

```
new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
  'node_modules', 
  '/absolute_path/modulename/**', 
  'node_modules/**', 
  'node_modules/modulename'
])
```

but webpack still triggers a rebuild when I change something inside my module.

I also tried adding [watchOptions.ignored](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions-ignored) to my config

```
webpackConfig.watchOptions = {
    ignored: /mymodulename/,
};
```

Comment: Would it exclude _everything_ it if you pass `() => false` as a matcher?

Comment: both `() => false` and `() => true` did not prevent webpack from rebuilding when a file changed

Comment: That's odd. If I were you my next step would be to debug webpack (which is not trivial indeed, but I don't have other options). Otherwise I cannot suggest anything else, from the documentation perspective it looks `() => true` (my bad yep) must ignore everything :-S